# What Collection/List to use

Tags: java, collections, types

I've got `Treasure` objects in a `TreasureCollectionDB` class.
The `TreasureCollectionDB` class has a `Map<Long, Treasure>` (long being an  id generated by the `TreasureCollectionDB`)    called treasures
and a second data collection/list  (available treasures).

The thing I need the other `Collection` or `List` to do is hold Treasures which I will add/remove through JSP pages. The Treasures in this list should be unique, but sorted alphabetically (if there's no data holder that does this by it self, I will write a sort method).
Anyone know what data holder I should use? Answers on the internet are confusing me as to which is most suitable.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Java Collection should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use)

Answer (score 4):

You may use TreeSet, that should give you the desired results.
Set doesn't allow duplicates and Tree maintains sorted order.
The Treasures may implement Comparable interface so that you can sort on the desired field(s).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create equals and hash code methods and also write a comparator. That comparator you may pass to a TreeSet and use SortedSet interface.